# javac -cp : cannot find symbol

Tags: java, command-line

I have 3 classes CustomerAddress, Customer and CustomerMain.

Customer has a import statement  :

```
import org.abc.customers.CustomerAddress;
```

While CustomerMain has an import statement :

```
import org.abc.customers.CustomerAddress; 
import org.abc.customers.Customer;
```

The package for all of these classes are

```
package org.abc.customer
```

Now, this program works fine on eclipse but when i try to compile and run on cmd prompt it would not compile

```
javac CustomerAddress.java
```

compiles fine

then since Customer depends on CustomerAddress

I give

```
javac -cp . Customer.java
```

but the compiler complains

```
error cannot find symbol CustomerAddress
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Compiled classes must exist within a folder structure that matches their package structure.  For example, a class `com.foo.bar.A` must exist within folders `com/foo/bar/`.
2. It really is far easier to do this sort of thing with an automated build tool like ant or maven.

If you're determined to build from the command line, you need to compile the independant classes first:

```
javac -d com/abc/customers/ CustomerAddress.java Customer.java CustomerMain.java
```

which *should* compile the classes and output them somewhere that javac will be able to resolve them from.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you are asking, but may I suggest using the built in export from eclipse?

Right click project -> 
export -> 
Runnable jar file -> 
Make sure you got Launch configuration right -> 
Choose the rest -> 
Click finish -> 
use your jar

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried by compiling, this way

```
javac *.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its an artifact of posting the question, but your package declaration has `customer` without an 's', and your import statements have `customers` *with* an 's'.  However, within the same package you don't need to do an `import`.

Comment: Thanks..Yes, its an artifact of posting the question. The import statement in the same package is redundant but does it have any side effects too or is it harmless for the code.

Comment: I believe it's harmless as long as your package names are spelled correctly :-)